# Posting JSON message with no key value pair Spray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-client

Here is an example of what I am trying to post to web service:

> Content-Type: application/json
>   "0100000001d238c42ec059b8c7747cd51debb4310108f6279d14957472822cf061a660828b000000006b483045022100d326257244e8cb86889509cf5b4717edf273d9e6e643f571c434753059eb01a902204aa761f44e89b55af0e2fa0caef580401a4ba61eebf8bc29020ce23f6fab1ee2012102661ac805eef8015c7c8d617c65ef327c4f2272fd5d9e97456a0d32d3bcf6f563ffffffff0288130000000000001976a91430a5d35558ade668b8829a2a0f60a3f10358327e88ac306f0100000000001976a914760fdb3483204406ddb73a45b20b7c9be61d0a7e88ac00000000"

Note that there is no key-value pair here. I am trying to use 'pipelining' to POST this, but I keep on getting the following error :

```
> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/chris/dev/coinprism-api/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/chris/dev/coinprism-api/src/main/scala/com/coinprism/transaction/TransactionBuilder.scala:102: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[spray.json.JsObject]
[error]     pipeline(Post(host + version + sendrawtransaction, msg))
```

Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
import TransactionHashFormat._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
val msg = ("""{"0100000001d238c42ec059b8c7747cd51debb4310108f6279d14957472822cf061a660828b000000006b483045022100d326257244e8cb86889509cf5b4717edf273d9e6e643f571c434753059eb01a902204aa761f44e89b55af0e2fa0caef580401a4ba61eebf8bc29020ce23f6fab1ee2012102661ac805eef8015c7c8d617c65ef327c4f2272fd5d9e97456a0d32d3bcf6f563ffffffff0288130000000000001976a91430a5d35558ade668b8829a2a0f60a3f10358327e88ac306f0100000000001976a914760fdb3483204406ddb73a45b20b7c9be61d0a7e88ac00000000"}""").asJson.asJsObject
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[TransactionHash] =
  addHeader("Content-Type" , "application/json") ~> sendReceive ~> unmarshal[TransactionHash]
pipeline(Post(host + version + sendrawtransaction, msg))
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

EDIT:

The API that I am trying to call:

http://docs.coinprism.apiary.io/#reference/transaction-signing-and-broadcasting/push-a-signed-raw-transaction-to-the-network/post?console=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

a) As others have already commented this isn't valid JSON so it will fail at runtime:

```
val msg = ("""{"0100000001d238c42ec059b8c7747cd51debb4310108f6279d14957472822cf061a660828b000000006b483045022100d326257244e8cb86889509cf5b4717edf273d9e6e643f571c434753059eb01a902204aa761f44e89b55af0e2fa0caef580401a4ba61eebf8bc29020ce23f6fab1ee2012102661ac805eef8015c7c8d617c65ef327c4f2272fd5d9e97456a0d32d3bcf6f563ffffffff0288130000000000001976a91430a5d35558ade668b8829a2a0f60a3f10358327e88ac306f0100000000001976a914760fdb3483204406ddb73a45b20b7c9be61d0a7e88ac00000000"}""").asJson.asJsObject
```

b) You cannot use marshallers because currently spray (1.3.2) only allows JSON objects and arrays to be marshalled. This was a requirement of the former JSON spec (RFC 4627) but this requirement has been lifted with the new RFC 7159. I created a ticket to fix this in the future https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/1034. The API you are targeting, however, expects a double-quoted JSON string.

c) This means you need cannot use marshalling (i.e. automatic conversion of Scala values to HTTP messages) in this case. This isn't a particular problem you just need to create the message yourself. Something like this should work:

```
val pipeline = sendReceive
val hash: String = "0100000001d238c42ec059b8c7747cd51debb4310108f6279d14957472822cf061a660828b000000006b483045022100d326257244e8cb86889509cf5b4717edf273d9e6e643f571c434753059eb01a902204aa761f44e89b55af0e2fa0caef580401a4ba61eebf8bc29020ce23f6fab1ee2012102661ac805eef8015c7c8d617c65ef327c4f2272fd5d9e97456a0d32d3bcf6f563ffffffff0288130000000000001976a91430a5d35558ade668b8829a2a0f60a3f10358327e88ac306f0100000000001976a914760fdb3483204406ddb73a45b20b7c9be61d0a7e88ac00000000"
val msg: String = "\"" + hash + "\""
val request = Post(host + version + sendrawtransaction, HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, msg))

// run request
pipeline(request) // receive result as Future[HttpResponse]
```

You need to understand that spray handles the Content-Type header specially: it isn't represented as a normal header but it is modeled as part of the HttpEntity.

Unfortunately, `unmarshal` doesn't work for the same reason as explained in b) so you need to extract the value yourself.

You should be able to do it roughly like this:

```
def extractJsonStringResult(res: HttpResponse): String = {
  // TODO: check status code
  import spray.json._
  res.entity.asString(HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`).parseJson match {
    case JsString(string) => string
    case _ => ??? // TODO: fail
  }
}
val pipeline = sendReceive ~> extractJsonStringResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because it is surrounded by curly braces does not make it valid json.  Spray does give you some options if you want to [post invalid json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#jsonformat-vs-rootjsonformat)

Can't you make the Content-Type "application/text" and post `msg` as a string?

Comment: Here is the api that I am trying to call http://docs.coinprism.apiary.io/#reference/transaction-signing-and-broadcasting/push-a-signed-raw-transaction-to-the-network/post?console=1

Comment: the error message I get from using `application/text` is the following [info] - must broadcast a transaction to the network *** FAILED ***
[info]   The future returned an exception of type: spray.httpx.UnsuccessfulResponseException, with message: Status: 415 Unsupported Media Type
[info]   Body: {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."}. (TransactionBuilderTest.scala:109)

Comment: Are you able to make a request outside of your spray application with a REST client like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes I just tried to use Postman. I was able to send the request with the `Content-Type` of `application/json` and the message body as just the string above. I'm getting another error message - but that is the error message I am expecting - specifically the error message `{
    "Message": "Error",
    "ErrorCode": "InvalidTransactionInput"
}`